# Python logging before you run logging.basicConfig?

Tags: python, logging, python-logging

It appears that if you invoke `logging.info()` **BEFORE** you run `logging.basicConfig`, the `logging.basicConfig` call doesn't have any effect. In fact, no logging occurs.

Where is this behavior documented? I don't really understand.

Comment: For python >= 3.8 basicConfig has a "force" argument that can be used to solve this.

Comment: note that the "force" argument can reset logging config on the root logger set by other modules, but if you have already instantiated any non-root loggers with eg `logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)` then it's too late to reconfigure those, even with `force`.  the only solution really is to do your logging config right at the top of the file, by the imports.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You can remove the default handlers and reconfigure logging like this:

```
# if someone tried to log something before basicConfig is called, Python creates a default handler that
# goes to the console and will ignore further basicConfig calls. Remove the handler if there is one.
root = logging.getLogger()
if root.handlers:
    for handler in root.handlers:
        root.removeHandler(handler)
logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s %(message)s',level=logging.DEBUG)
```

Comment: To be used verbatim. If you -like me- tried to reuse a previous logger instantiated like this: `logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)` and try to loop in `logger.handlers` it would not work.

Comment: What's the "if root.handlers:" good for? Iterating an empty sequence has no effect. Is it possible that root.handlers is some other, non-sequence false value? (It isn't on my system)

Comment: Came in handy for debugging logging issue with AWS Lambdas. Looks like they install some handler with name `LambdaLoggingHandler` during lambda bootstrapping. Removing installed handler solved the problem.

Answer (score 13):

Yes.

You've asked to log something.  Logging must, therefore, fabricate a default configuration.  Once logging is configured... well... it's configured.

> "With the logger object configured,
> the following methods create log
> messages:"

Further, you can read about creating handlers to prevent spurious logging.  But that's more a hack for bad implementation than a useful technique.

There's a trick to this.

1. No module can do anything except `logging.getLogger()` requests at a global level.
2. Only the `if __name__ == "__main__":` can do a logging configuration.

If you do logging at a global level in a module, then you may force logging to fabricate it's default configuration.

Don't do `logging.info` globally in any module.  If you absolutely think that you must have `logging.info` at a global level in a module, then you have to configure logging *before* doing imports.  This leads to unpleasant-looking scripts.

Comment: No, I was wrong - apparently this is by design as basicConfig is called from .info et al to ensure a logger is installed. It still seems like odd behaviour to me.

Comment: At a global level, if a module uses `logging.getLogger()` then its WARNING and ERROR are written to stderr, but INFO are *just discarded!* I guess this behavior makes sense, but it might not be a good trade-off in your app.

Comment: I'm not sure what the right approach is -- I guess any function that needs logging is probably because it has side effects, and it's better to avoid side effects during module import.

Answer (score 11):

This answer from Carlos A. Ibarra is in principle right, however that implementation might break since you are iterating over a list that might be changed by calling removeHandler(). This is unsafe.
Two alternatives are:

```
while len(logging.root.handlers) > 0:
    logging.root.removeHandler(logging.root.handlers[-1])
logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s %(message)s',level=logging.DEBUG)
```

or:

```
logging.root.handlers = []
logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s %(message)s',level=logging.DEBUG)
```

where the first of these two using the loop is the safest (since any destruction code for the handler can be called explicitly inside the logging framework). Still, this is a hack, since we rely on logging.root.handlers to be a list.

Comment: could also do `list(logging.root.handlers)` to make a copy

Answer (score 7):

Here's the one piece of the puzzle that the above answers didn't mention... and then it will all make sense:  the "root" logger -- which is used if you call, say, logging.info() before logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG) -- *has a default logging level of WARNING*.

That's why logging.info() and logging.debug() don't do anything: because you've configured them *not to*, by... um... not configuring them.

Possibly related (this one bit me): when NOT calling basicConfig, I didn't seem to be getting my debug messages, even though I set my handlers to DEBUG level.  After a bit of hair-pulling, I found you have to set the level of the custom *logger* to be DEBUG as well.  If your logger is set to WARNING, then setting a handler to DEBUG (by itself) won't get you any output on logger.info() and logger.debug().

Answer (score 3):

Ran into this same issue today and, as an alternative to the answers above, here's my solution.

```py
import logging
import sys

logging.debug('foo') # IRL, this call is from an imported module

if __name__ == '__main__':
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO, force=True)
    logging.info('bar') # without force=True, this is not printed to the console
```

Here's what the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.basicConfig) say about the `force` argument.

> If this keyword argument is specified as true, any existing handlers
> attached to the root logger are removed and closed, before carrying
> out the configuration as specified by the other arguments.

Comment: This is the correct, modern solution - but it only works for Python >=3.8

Answer (score 1):

A cleaner version of the answer given by @paul-kremer is:

```
while len(logging.root.handlers):
    logging.root.removeHandler(logging.root.handlers[-1])
```

Note: it is generally safe to assume logging.root.handlers will always be a list (see: [https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/cebe9ee988837b292f2c571e194ed11e7cd4abbb/Lib/logging/**init**.py#L1253](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/cebe9ee988837b292f2c571e194ed11e7cd4abbb/Lib/logging/__init__.py#L1253))

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did.

I wanted to log to a file which has a name configured in a config-file and also get the debug-logs of the config-parsing.

TL;DR; This logs into a buffer until everything to configure the logger is available

```py
# Log everything into a MemoryHandler until the real logger is ready.
# The MemoryHandler never flushes (flushLevel 100 is above CRITICAL) automatically but only on close.
# If the configuration was loaded successfully, the real logger is configured and set as target of the MemoryHandler
# before it gets flushed by closing.
# This means, that if the log gets to stdout, it is unfiltered by level
root_logger = logging.getLogger()
root_logger.setLevel(logging.NOTSET)
stdout_logging_handler = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stderr)
tmp_logging_handler = logging.handlers.MemoryHandler(1024 * 1024, 100, stdout_logging_handler)
root_logger.addHandler(tmp_logging_handler)

config: ApplicationConfig = ApplicationConfig.from_filename('config.ini')

# because the records are already logged, unwanted ones need to be removed
filtered_buffer = filter(lambda record: record.levelno >= config.main_config.log_level, tmp_logging_handler.buffer)
tmp_logging_handler.buffer = filtered_buffer

root_logger.removeHandler(tmp_logging_handler)
logging.basicConfig(filename=config.main_config.log_filename, level=config.main_config.log_level, filemode='wt')
logging_handler = root_logger.handlers[0]
tmp_logging_handler.setTarget(logging_handler)
tmp_logging_handler.close()
stdout_logging_handler.close()
```