# Package __init__ for a test

Tags: python, unit-testing, initialization, package

I have the following structure in a project:

```
app/
    __init__.py
    main.py
    tests/
        __init__.py
        test_a.py
        test_b.py
```

I would like to initialize logging for tests under the `tests` package. I placed the initialization code in `app/tests/__init__.py` under the assumption that it is run before any test is run, however I've discovered this is not the case.

How can I make this initialization code run in the following scenarios?

- When running `python test_a.py` from the command prompt
- When running `test_a.py` as a unit-test under eclipse\aptana\pycharm
- When running the entire test suite under eclipse\aptana\pycharm

Comment: If I'm going about this the wrong way, please let me know. e.g. if I could simply have a `setup_logging.py` and import it at the start of each test. I simply wanted to minimize boiler plate code...

Comment: If you run `test_a.py` directly it is not considered as part of the package, just as a regular file. So, `__init__.py` has nothing to do here. Just commenting, I don't know the solution to your problem though...

Answer (score 0):

You can use logger config files for normal run and tests, which is the most secure way to have different configurations.

The 'workaround' way is to re-create loggers. You've probably just added new loggers in __init__.py? Once configured, logging keeps it config and only allows extending.
However you can try re-creating the whole logger, as described here:
[Python logging before you run logging.basicConfig?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1943747/python-logging-before-you-run-logging-basicconfig)
e.g.:

```
root = logging.getLogger()
if root.handlers:
    for handler in root.handlers:
        root.removeHandler(handler)
# now create your test config
logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s %(message)s',level=logging.DEBUG)
```

Add this code to your test.py file, or add it into __init__.py but you might probably need:

```
from tests import *
```

to make it execute in the tests.