# How do I add logging errors in my lambda function?

Tags: python, sql, aws-lambda, mariadb

I added a few, I'm not sure if any more would be useful. Also, is this all I have to do to write a lambda? I was given very little instruction on how to do it. It returns the result from the query like it's supposed to. I don't see anything wrong with it except for adding some logging exceptions?

```
import logging
import os
import sys
import mariadb as mdb

cnxn = mdb.connect(
user="username",
password="pass",
host="host",
port=port,
database="database"
)

cur=cnxn.cursor()
SQL_QUERY="CALL STORED_PROCEDURE();"
cur.execute(SQL_QUERY)
row=cur.fetchone()

def name_of_handler(event=None, context=None):
    try:
        cur.execute(SQL_QUERY)
        cnxn.commit()
    except mdb.Error as e:
        print(f"Error: {e}")
    except Exception as e:
        logging.exception(e)

    print(row)
    cnxn.close()

name_of_handler()
```

UPDATE: Nevermind, how do I write a message saying "executed successfully?" I see the records did insert into the database, but there is no confirmation in the python code.

Comment: Where in your code do you have a `lambda`?

Comment: the function is the lambda function. it's the "name_of_handler", which is the lambda handler

Comment: That's not a `lambda`, that's just a regular function.

Comment: Not a lambda...

Comment: oh! how do i make it a lambda?

Comment: Why do you want to make it a `lambda`? It's fine as it is

Comment: because i need to run my lambda function on a scheduler? im not sure if i can do that with a regular function...im using AWS lambda for this. i think i need to read up more on it

Comment: Stored procedures should be executed with cursors callproc() method instead of execute().

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using python Logging with AWS Lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37703609/using-python-logging-with-aws-lambda)